# How to use a variable to identify possible columns in a SQLAlchemy table?

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

Currently, I'm brute forcing a query into a SQLite table using SQLAlchemy, such as the below example:

```
def get_classes(race):
    if race == "Hill Dwarf":
        classes = session.query(AcceptableCharClass.Char_Class).filter(AcceptableCharClass.Dwarf_Hill)
    elif race == "Gray Dwarf":
        classes = session.query(AcceptableCharClass.Char_Class).filter(AcceptableCharClass.Dwarf_Gray)
    elif race == "Mountain Dwarf":
        classes = session.query(AcceptableCharClass.Char_Class).filter(AcceptableCharClass.Dwarf_Mountain)
```

The SQLAlchemy for the table is:

```
class AcceptableCharClass(Base):
    """Create the SQLAlchemy structure for the existing DB"""
    __tablename__: str = "Class_by_Race"  # Race vs. Class
    Char_Class: str = Column(String, primary_key=True)
    Dwarf_Gray: bool = Column(Boolean, default=False)
    Dwarf_Hill: bool = Column(Boolean, default=False)
    Dwarf_Mountain: bool = Column(Boolean, default=False)
```

Rather than manually calling each column in the table AcceptableCharClass, is there a way to pass the column name as a variable? Something like:

```
def get_classes(race):
    classes = session.query(AcceptableCharClass.Char_Class).filter(AcceptableCharClass.race)
```

Otherwise, there is a lot of redundant code that only differs by the column name, which tells me I'm doing it wrong.

Comment: Please provide the definition of `AcceptableCharClass`.

Comment: @Ilja Everilä 

AcceptableCharClass is a table that holds boolean values for character races vs. character classes, i.e. which classes is a particular race eligible to be.

Comment: It is best to provide it in the question itself, as code.